# Shifting a CAD file from ATS77 MTM 5 to NAD83 CSRS UTM 20

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, cad, nad83

Looking to make the coordinate system shift in ArcMAP (for Nova Scotia) between ATS77 MTM 5 and NAD83 CSRS...NTv2 file?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to, but you will need the NTv2 transformation files for New Brunswick. They're available for download from [GeoNB](http://www.snb.ca/geonb1/e/DC/catalogue-E.asp).

The file you're interested in is NB7783v2.GSB. Once extracted from the downloaded zip file, place it in your ArcGIS home, pedata\ntv2\canada.

EDIT: Okay, so most of the information above is incorrect because I assumed New Brunswick and Jason in interested in Nova Scotia. Nova Scotia has a different NTv2 file, and you may need to purchase it. It is listed on the a [price list](http://www.novascotia.ca/snsmr/pdf/GEO_INFO_RETAIL_PRICE_LIST.pdf). The [referring page](http://www.novascotia.ca/snsmr/land/products/coordinate4.asp) mentions that a data use license is required for NS778301.gsb.

On the other hand, Service Nova Scotia has an [online coordinate transformation service](http://gis13.nsgc.gov.ns.ca/sns_webclient/NSCTWS_ClientWebApp.aspx), but it only takes GML, Text, or keyboard.

General information: NTv2 (National Transformation version 2) is a gridded file of offsets between two geographic coordinate reference systems. In this case, they are ATS77 and NAD83 (CSRS).

Comment: I was able to get that NTv2 transformation for Nova Scotia (as I needed) and everything worked out well!  - Thanks for your help, much appreciated.