# ATS77 MTM 5 to NAD83 CSRS UTM 20N Coordinate Converter?

Tags: convert, utm, nad83

I've been looking for a simple way to check the accuracy of my transformation using a set of coordinates for a single point but have been unable to find an online tool or piece of desktop software that can do the ATS77 MTM 5 to NAD83 CSRS UTM 20N conversion since Franson CoordTrans and GeoSuite Calc are unable to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apart from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101705/shifting-a-cad-file-from-ats77-mtm-5-to-nad83-csrs-utm-20 GDAL cs2cs should do it, if you have the right ntv2 grid file. The official site seems to have moved to http://geonova.novascotia.ca/

Comment: I have the correct Ntv2 file and will have to look into GDAL cs2cs as a way of applying it. Thanks for the suggestion!